# how do we print this pattern in java using for loops (please don't use functions except the main function)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
--g   h   i   j--
----d   e   f----
------b   c------
--------a--------
```

how do we print this pattern in java using for loops .i don't want to print the pattern using "System.out.print()".
i tried using nested for loops but got stuck up. i cannot understand that after printing the first line how do i shift to the second  line .

dash(-) refers to space

this is not my homework...i have just been trying out new programs for practice.

Comment: does dash(-) corresponds to a space?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Is this homework?

Comment: We're not doing your homework for you.  Try something, and post your code.

Comment: No functions? :( That could be some nice tri-recursion!

Comment: Hint: I would create it from the bottom->up, unless there is a restriction on doing as such. (Using an ArrayList or StringBuilder can provided temporary storage of the output.)

Comment: No functions? Technically `System.out.println();` is one, too.

Comment: @BhushanFirake yes dash(-) does refer to space

Comment: @user1936887: Go to http://programmingsimplified.com .This site offers "Print Patterns" section in C language. You can get the logic there for many different patterns.

Answer (score 8):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i ++) {
    System.out.println("--g   h   i   j--");
    System.out.println("----d   e   f----");
    System.out.println("------b   c------");
    System.out.println("--------a--------");
}
```

Comment: +1, I forgot the for loop in my answer.

Comment: this is how you do it in real world ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your only requirement is to print that pattern??

This will do the job:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("--g   h   i   j--");
    System.out.println("----d   e   f----");
    System.out.println("------b   c------");
    System.out.println("--------a--------");
}
```

Please consider adding all the information we need to answer your question in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 2):

This code will print exactly what you need using only for loops in the main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 2;
    int nr = 3;
    char base = 'g';
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < x; ++j) {
        System.out.print("-");
        }
        int letNr = 4 - i;
        for(int j = 0; j < letNr - 1; ++j) {
            System.out.print((char)(base + j) + "   ");
        }
        System.out.print((char)(base + letNr - 1)); 
        for(int j = 0; j < x; ++j) {
        System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();
        x+=2;
        base = (char)(base - nr );
        nr--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want a proper answer you will want this

```
String[][] letters = { {"a"}, {"b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i", "j"} };
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
    int amountOfHashes = (i+1) * 2;
    String outputString = "";
    for (int i2 = 0; i < amountOfHashes; i ++) {
        outputString += "-";
    }
    String tempArray = letters[3 - i];
    for (int i2 = 0; i < tempArray; i ++) {
        if (i2 != 0) { outputString += " "; }
        outputString += tempArray[i2];
    }
    for (int i2 = 0; i < amountOfHashes; i ++) {
        outputString += "-";
    }
}
```

Haven't tested it so you will have to debug it

Answer (score 0):

Try::

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i ++) {
    System.out.println("--g   h   i   j--\n----d   e   f----\n------b   c------\n--------a--------");

}
```